# Which one is an agent noun?

Tags: sentence-construction

> A number of people take a show once a day.

'number' is an agent noun of the verb or 'people' is an agent noun of the verb? 'number' means amount but is the subject so I'm confusing.

Comment: Don't get so hung up on terminology. I don't understand "take a show" here - but whatever it means, ***a number of people*** do it. And ***collectively***, that highlighted string of words is a ***noun phrase***, which is the ***syntactic subject*** of the sentence. It's really irrelevant that in some ***other*** contexts, both the word ***number*** and the word ***people*** are "nouns" all on their own. What matters is they're joined together with other words *(**a, of**)* to make a noun capable of being used as the subject in ***this*** sentence.

Comment: "take a show" should probable be "take **in** a show". In American English, "take in" can mean attending an event (usually entertainment or sport). https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/take-in#take-in__17

Answer (score 1):

"**A number of people**" is a noun phrase and the agent. The agent is the doer of the verb.

We can see this in the passive:

A daily shower is taken **by a number of people.**

In passive forms, the agent is introduced by "**by**".